# cache secrets from aws secret manager in lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm building an API with AWS api gateway and lambda functions. In these functions, I need to access a postgresql database. I'm using NodeJS and I'm using the npm-package `pg` to communicate with the database.

My database credentials are stored in AWS secret manager. The problem is: every time a lambda function is called (eg. an andpoint of my API gateway is reached), these credentials are fetched from the secret manager. I see that 10,000 API calls cost $0,05, so it's not THAT expensive, but is there somehow a way to cache these credentials?

My (simplified) code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const secretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager({ region: 'eu-central-1' });

const getSecret = async (SecretId) => {
    const response = await secretsManager.getSecretValue({ SecretId }).promise();
    
    return response.SecretString;
};

const connectToDb = async () => {
    const credentials = JSON.parse(await getSecret('database/credentials'));

    const connection = new Pool({
        host: credentials.host,
        port: credentials.port,
        user: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password,
        database: credentials.database
    });

    return connection;
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const connection = await connectToDb();
    const client = await connection.connect();

    // do stuff here...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading up on [AWS Lambda container reuse](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/). Global variables, such as your `const secretsManager` variable, are only initialized once, when the Lambda container is initialized. That means every time that container is reused for another function invocation that variable doesn't have to be reinitialized.

If you moved this line of code:

```
const credentials = JSON.parse(await getSecret('database/credentials'));
```

So that it is executed on function initialization, instead of being triggered via the handler function, then the function would only query SecretsManager once per container creation, instead of once per handler invocation.

---

Per [this Lambda update](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/aws-lambda-es-modules-top-level-await-node-js-14/), I believe this should work:

```
const getSecret = async (SecretId) => {
    const response = await secretsManager.getSecretValue({ SecretId }).promise();
    
    return response.SecretString;
};
const credentials = JSON.parse(await getSecret('database/credentials'));
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasnt' aware of this. Can you please guide me where to put this line of code then, because it is already outside the handler function (it get's called in the handler function)?

Comment: The problem I'm having is because it's an async/await function, I need to put it in a async function, am I right?